# Opening a JPG file by a script in crontab

Tags: linux, bash, cron, gnome

I'm trying to make a pomodoro script, just for fun haha. The ideia is that every 30 minutes, a pic pop up on the screen... so its coffee time! ;)
I planned something simple, like a scrip that opens a pic, run by the crontab.
I got a script that opens a jpg image using EOG. Something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
eog -n /home/lscardeal/Pictures/pic.jpg
```

It works when i run it myself, but it doesn't open the file  when its run by the crontab. My crontab runs the script, but the pic doesn't open. How can i make it work?

thx

Comment: run it using su e.g. su `eog -n /home/lscardeal/Pictures/pic.jpg`

Comment: STDIN/OUT for cron jobs is not your session

Comment: If the answer solved your question, you should click the little check mark next to it, to reward erigobeli and to let people know that no further help is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if this script works:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Export DISPLAY
export DISPLAY=:0.0

#Call Gnome EOG
/usr/bin/eog -f /home/user/image.png &

#Time to display
sleep 100

killall eog
```

Tks